# Get the select value to show the value in the input html

Tags: php

I am using PHP to create the select dropdown from database table, my problem is how to get the dropdrop down value to show in the input html?

Below is my coding:

```html
<select class="form-control blank" id="parentid" name="parentid" title="parentid">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option value="0">New Category</option>
<?php
 $sql_incharge = 'select * from folder_category where status=1 order by id';
$arr_incharge = db_conn_select($sql_incharge);
foreach ($arr_incharge as $rs_incharge) {
$folder_location = $rs_incharge['folder_location'];
echo '<option value="' . $rs_incharge['id'] . '">' . $rs_incharge['name'] . '</option>';

                            }
                            ?>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text"  class="form-control blank" id="status" name="status" title="status" value="<?php echo $folder_location;?>">
```

Below is my database table, I want to get `folder_location` value when I've selected in the dropdown box:

[image: Table]

This is my output, how if I've selected `100-1 Perundangan`, then the below empty box will show the folder location is `MPK 100 Pentadbiran` value.
[image: Output]

Comment: You need to add javascript code, May be an ajax call using id to get "Folder name"

Comment: @Vishal Thanks your comment. Can you write down the sample ajax call using id below?  Then if correct, I can give you mark.

Answer (score 1):

You need below javascript code to get folder name using ajax call. It's not been tested so please modify code accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#parentid').on('change', function () {
        var record_id = $(this).val();
        getFolderName(record_id);
    });
});

function getFolderName(record_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/url/get-folder",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            id: record_id
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            // Add code if required
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // Handle Success condition
            $("#status").val(data.name)
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Handle Error
        }
    });
}
```